# lavalink not authorizing. and "no mapping /node/{node}/authorize

Tags: python, discord, bots

I cant get the client to authorize with lavalink server on REST request.
its authorizing just fine with ws, but that is not supported anymore.

lmk if you need more of the code for troubleshooting, all suggestion is highly appriciated!

this is the part of the referred code:

```
def add_node():
    response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.100:2333/node/default-node/authorize', json={
        "host": "192.168.1.100",
        "port": 2333,
        "password": "youshallnotpass",
        "region": "eu",
        "secure": "default-node"
    })
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Node added successfully")
    else:
        print(f"Error adding node: {response.text}")
add_node()
bot.run(token)



# Play a track
@bot.command(aliases=['p', 'play'])
async def play_track(ctx, url: str):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
    if not ctx.author.voice.channel.permissions_for(ctx.me).connect:
        return await ctx.send("I don't have permission to connect to your voice channel.")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        
        # Get the bot's user ID from the context
        player = lavalink_client.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint=f"http://192.168.1.100:2333/{<bot_id>}")
        await player.connect(ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
        headers = {"Authorization": "youshallnotpass"}
        payload = {"identifier": url}
        async with session.post(f"http://192.168.1.100:2333/loadtracks", json=payload, headers=headers) as resp:
            data = await resp.json()
        track = data['tracks'][0]
        await player.play(track)
```

Have tried bruteforcing correct mapping of the URL.
If i only use `"http://192.168.1.100:2333"` as URl I get "authentication failed from ip.ip.ip.ip".
im running fredboat/lavalink image in docker for the lavalink.
password is correct for sure...
The javalink version is lavalink 3.7.1 / latest image on hub.docker.com.
Have tried updating every dependencies, tried different variabels that i found online.
asked chatGPT bot - which tell me to look at the documentation, which i have tried without luck.
my if / else statement gives me:

> Error adding node: {"timestamp":1674265690303,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found","path":"/nodes/default/authorize"}"